# Finding a formula for a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

This is an exercise from conway book that I am stuck at. I first tried to use the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem but to no avail. Also the region on which f is defined is not guaranteed to be a simply connected region, so I can't see how to follow the hint... Could anyone help me how to find a formula for f?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) and [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) to prove that the only such function is the constant $f(z)=1$.

Comment: could you tell me what happens if f has zeros?

Comment: @Keith It will have a finite number of zeros, so you can use Rouché's theorem and shift it by constant functions to derive a contradiction.

Comment: could you tell me how I can be certain that the function has only finite zeros? Can't it have countably infinite zeros?

Comment: Oh I can see that a closed disc is compact...

Comment: @Keith Exactly. Therefore, if it had infinitely many zeros the set of zeros would have an accumulation point, so that the function would be constant zero by the identity theorem, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Show that a function $f$ which is analytic in a neighbourhood of the closed disk $\overline{B}(0,1)$ and which has modulus 1 on the circle $|z|=1$, is a finite [Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product). Note that $f$ has no zeros on $|z|=1$, and it has only a finite number of zeros inside $|z|<1$. Let $B$ be the finite Blaschke product with the
 zeros of $f$ (and with the same multiplicities). Then consider the ratios $f/B$ and $B/f$ and, by using the Maximum Modulus Principle, show that $f/B$ is a constant of modulus $1$.

Comment: Blaschke product?  How is such a specific characterization of f possible from such a weak condition?

Comment: See for example Fatou theorem: http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fricain/Blaschke-finite-characterization.pdf

Comment: what about zeros outside the closed ball B(0;1)? How should I deal with those zeros? Now, what bothers me most seems to be the condition that f is defined on a region bigger than just B(0;1)....Could you explain in more detail about the formula for f in its domain of definition?